# Unfortunately, Launcher3 has stopped

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, simulator

I get this error in Visual Studio, when I run my Xamarin application in built-in simulator.

```
Unfortunately, Launcher3 has stopped
```

And I wanted to write the solution that I found

for people who are searching the same problem:

Comment: Posting self-answered questions is okay, but please do it [correctly](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has solved when I wait or re-launched the application.

The reason of this error is this :

The simulator is not opened on the first run, and it gets this error.